# why "migrations" and "user" tables are created after running "php artisan migrate --env=local"

Tags: laravel

i am trying to insert data in database using **laravel framework**. but it gives me error like **sqlstate hy000 access is denied**. after that i run the command **php artisan migrate --env=local**. after that error is removed but it created two tables automatically **name: "users" and "Migrations**". now i don't know why these two tables are created automatically. please help me regarding these tables. Thankyou!

Comment: The `users` table is a migration that exist in a fresh install of Laravel in the `database/migrations` directory. The migrations table is used to check if a migration has already run or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`users` table is a default migration that exists on a fresh install of Laravel. Many sites require some kind of user login, so Laravel includes a table for users by default.

You can find this migration in `database/migrations/` folder inside your Laravel project folder.

This table is used for the Laravel Auth (basic user login / registration system) which can be set up simply by typing `php artisan make:auth` into your terminal inside the Laravel project folder.

This will create another migration for you for password resets.

The `migrations` table allows Laravel to know which migrations have already been executed, so for example if you were to run `php artisan migrate` again after running `php artisan make:auth`, it would know to only run the password resets migration, as the user migration had already been completed previously.

You can read more about Laravel's migrations in the [Laravel Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/migrations)